# How to implement TrackMessageSizeFilter in Atmosphere?

Tags: java, jquery, web.xml, atmosphere

I'm working on a project which uses Atmosphere Framework jQuery-jersey-pubsub. I wish to track the size of my messages and Atmosphere already has the feature, namely [TrackMessageSizeFilter](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/blob/master/modules/cpr/src/main/java/org/atmosphere/client/TrackMessageSizeFilter.java). I have included this file on the server, also I have set `trackMessageLength: true` on my client. I have also included the entry

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcastFilterClasses</param-name>
    <param-value>org.atmosphere.client.TrackMessageSizeFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
```

I have also tried

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcastFilterClasses</param-name>
    <param-value>com.mypackage.TrackMessageSizeFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Neither seems to append the message size to my messages. How do I acheive that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the TrackMessageSizeInterceptor instead by just installing it via the init-param.

https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Multiple-messages-arrive-as-single-response-body-or-message-received-are-incomplete

-- Jeanfrancois